# Select sub element based on classes it has

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the HTML that I have

```
<ul id="QBS">
  <li>
    <a class="qb_mode starting Rodgers" href="#">See Stats</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="qb_mode Manning" href="#">See Stats</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="qb_mode Brady" href="#">See Stats</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to find this unordered list, then tell which item has the starting qb class and then return the class that has their name (brady rodger manning) etc.

What's throwing me in a loop is the fact that the link is wrapped in the list element.

Here is what I am trying:

```
element = $("#qbs"); // pretty sure I want this vs getElementbyDocumentID
children = element.children();` // gets me all the list elements

for (i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
  grandchild = children[i].children();
  ???? How would I get the 3rd class on this element?
}
```

Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Do you have to organize the tags this way?  Could you put the QB name into an attribute that isn't the class?

Comment: shouldn't `$("#qbs");` be `$("#QBS");`

Comment: i cant mess with the html. its generated from somewhere else where i cant modify the rails code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, how about:

```
var name = $('#QBS a.qb_mode.starting').prop('class').replace(/\s*(qb_mode|starting)\s*/g,'');
console.log(name); // Rogers
```

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/nQNKQ/1).

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var allClasses = $("#QBS").find('li a[class^="qb_"]')
     .map(function () { 
          return this.className.split(" ").pop();
}).get();
console.log(allClasses);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux7VN/)**

Provided the class started with qb_* is at the beginning and you want to take only the last class of the match.

if all your class names are qb_mode then:

```
var allClasses = $("#QBS").find('.qb_mode').map(function () {
    return this.className.split(" ").pop();
}).get();
```

if you want all of them then:

```
var allClasses = $("#QBS").find('.qb_mode').map(function () {
    var cls = this.className.replace(/qb_mode/,'');
    return cls.trim().split(/\W+/);
}).get();
console.log(allClasses);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrKX/)**

Comment: You could just use `a.qb_mode` instead of looking for a class that starts with `qb`

Comment: @cfs yes if that is all he has, but looking at his statement one has `qb` class guess it might be anything that starts with qb.

Comment: the a.qb_mode works well also. this is pretty solid just playing around with the code a bit.

Comment: thanks i liked the other one which was a bit shorter better. i voted up some of your newest answers also though

Answer (score 1):

```
a=document.getElementById('QBS');
var b=a.getElementsByClassName("qb_mode");
var i, j=b.length, result=[];
for(i=0;i<j;i++) {
  c=b[i].className.split(" ");
  result.push(c.pop());
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3Amt3/

```
var names=[];

$("#QBS > li a").each(function(i){
    var a=$(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    names[i]=a[(a.length-1)];
    console.log("Name  is " + names[i]);    
 });
```

or a more precise selector

```
 $("#QBS > li a.qb_mode").each( ....
```